# How To Automatically Start iMacros Javascript Upon Browser Loading

Tags: javascript, firefox, automation, macros, imacros

This question is specific to the iMacros suite in particular.

What is the best way to go about **automatically starting a javascript file that controls my macros** inside firefox?

Basically, I have an imacros.js file that calls a series of imacros.iim files. How can I run this javascript automatically?

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is the only viable solution? http://wiki.imacros.net/Browser_Automation#Shortcuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support has been working for me, though first I launch firefox, pause so imacros can load, and then "relaunch" my script as described, which opens in the already open and loaded imacros.